# Regex for nested BBTags

Tags: c#, regex

I have found/made a regex that parses bbtags great but it has one flaw, it doesn't treat nested tag that are are the same as the containing tag.

The BBTag parser I made relies on the fact that the outermost tags can contain sub tags which works fine if nested tag is not the same as the containing tag

The regex I am using is: `@"\[color=((.|\n)*?)(?:\s*)\]((.|\n)*?)\[/color(?:\s*)\]"`

Test application ( simple console app )

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\[color=((.|\n)*?)(?:\s*)\]((.|\n)*?)\[/color(?:\s*)\]");

var matches = regex.Matches("[color=red]This is red.[color=green] This be green.[/color] Still red here.[/color] This has no color [color=green] and this is green.[/color]").Cast<Match>().Where(x => x.Success).ToList();
if (matches.Count > 0)
    for(int m = 0; m < matches.Count; m++)
        for (int i = 0; i < matches[m].Groups.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("({0}) - {1} -> {2}", m, i, matches[m].Groups[i]);
else
    Console.WriteLine("No matches.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a BBCode library. [Codekicker.BBCode](http://bbcode.codeplex.com/) parses BBCode, converts it to HTML or text and can give you a transformable AST.

Regex is not made for hierarchical parsing. You'll have a hard time making this work. Bugs will be hard to find. Security issues will arise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match this kind of things (that can be nested) with regex, you can use the balancing group technic:

```
(?:[^][]|(?<Open>\[([a-z]+)[^]]*])|(?<Content-Open>\[/\1]))+(?(Open)(?!))
```

You can find interesting informations about this technic [here](http://retkomma.wordpress.com/2009/09/26/regex-balancing-group-in-depth/).